# Should all our Model classes be case classes?

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala and trying to understand its various constructs and their use-cases, so coming down to case-classes, They are great for pattern matching etc.

So looking at MVC point of view, should our all our Models be case classes to leverage this feature ?

I looked at the play framework's sample code snippets and found an example where a model class was defined as a case class.

Answer (score 2):

If you have models as in [swing component models](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/swingmodels/), e.g., table models, in mind, then case classes might not be the best choice. Case classes are a good choice when they are (observationally) immutable, which is usually the case if you use them to represent data retrieved from a data base. For swing models, how ever, this might not be the case, e.g., if the user is allowed to change the table data.

Comment: Not sure how hard it would be to fit into swing, but you can always have Lenses.

Comment: You probably can, but the resulting combination sounds screams "wrong design decision" to me. Assuming the table is meant to be edited, you would then choose an immutable data structure - already sounds odd to me - just to put a layer of lenses on top to make it sort of mutable again (and much more complex).

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon. There are various libraries, e.g. [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat/) for MongoDB, that will store and retrieve case class instances from your datastore of choice.